# grave threat -- meaning?

Tags: meaning, idioms

Example with [a context](http://www.bostonglobe.com/opinion/2014/12/23/ruble-crisis-threatens-putin-hero-like-status/79q8sySYp030cngUp0xvbP/story.html):

> Both Washington and Wall Street are watching, wondering what Putin's government does next. But it now appears safe to say: The Ukraine crisis has become **a grave threat** to the Russian economy.

How do you understand the phrase *grave threat*? Although I'm not one hundred percent sure what it means exactly, I'll take a guess. Does it mean that this is not just your regular thread, but it's much more than that in that this kind of thread is going to cost you your life, meaning, you're going to be dead if you don't do something?

Comment: Was the guess inspired by the noun *grave* (also *graveyard*)? Interesting--that has never crossed my mind before. I think this adjective *grave* is closer to *gravity* than to the noun *grave* (as in *cemetery plot*).

Comment: Well, there's the expression "empty threat" which means it's an idle threat - nothing's gonna happen to you. The one above might just be the opposite - it's gonna be your downfall (you're gonna end up buried in a grave). I don't know though. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: That's fair. I just thought it's interesting, how we learn new words. For me, this phrase, *a grave threat*, reminds me of another phrase, *the gravity of the situation*.

Comment: See [***grave***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/grave) sense 2b: "seriously contrary to what is right or desirable; extremely bad".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Grave* here has nothing to do with the sort of *grave* you dig (which is from a Germanic word), or with the *gravy* you put on your potatoes (which derives from a misreading of Old French {grane}, 'stew', as {graue}) but with the *grave* from Latin *gravis*, 'heavy', as in *gravity* (which has its source in the ancient *gravitas*, now suddenly fashionable again).

A *grave* threat is a *weighty* one—a very serious threat, which could cause severe damage to the Russian economy.

Comment: So, something along the lines of "grave consequences".

Comment: @CookieMonster Yes. *Grave* is a word diplomats are very fond of. It suggests that people are thinking *very hard* about something, which is somehow more troubling than if they were *doing* something about it.